# Whats the efficient way to find the count of the number of objects that are direct or indirect children of that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, javascript-objects

an array of JavaScript objects such as:
let objectArray =

```
[
{ id: 0, parentId: null}, 
{ id: 4, parentId: 3},
{ id: 1, parentId: 0}, 
{ id: 3, parentId: 2},
{ id: 2, parentId: 0}
]
```

where parentId, when not null, references another object in the array with id = parentId. The objects form a relationship that can be visualized like a tree:

[image]

we have to create a function in JS, that given an id returns the count of the number of objects that are direct or indirect children of that object. For example, if the function is given the value 3, it should return 1, if the function is given the value 0, it should return 4.

What i tried,

```
var count = 0;
var selected = [];

let objectArray = [
      { id: 0, parentId: null},
      { id: 4, parentId: 3},
      { id: 1, parentId: 0},
      { id: 3, parentId: 2},
      { id: 2, parentId: 0}
];


var factorial = function(objectArray, selected, num) {
  // console.log('5 - Array = ', Array );
  console.log('6 - selected = ', selected );
  // do stuff here

  for (var i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    console.log('19 -  num = ', num );
    console.log('20 -  i =', i, objectArray[i] );
    console.log('21-  parent_id =', i, objectArray[i].parentId  );

    if ( objectArray[i].parentId  === num ) {
        console.log('   yes with num =', num );
        count = count + 1;
        selected.push(objectArray[i]);

        // selected.pop(selected[i]);

        console.log(' 18-  count = ', count );
    }
    console.log('20 ============ done =========== i= ', i );

    console.log(' ============ selected ==== ', selected );
    console.log('25 ============ count =========== ', count );
  }


  // if (selected.length >= 0 ) { // terminal case
  if ( selected.length == 0 ) { // terminal case
  // if ( count >= 6 ) {
    console.log('29-  %%%%%%%%%%%% if selected.length =', selected.length);
    console.log('29-  %%%%%%%%%%%% if  count %%%%%%%%% ', count );
    return count;
  } else { // block to execute
    console.log(' ****** in else --  now calling Selected Arr ******');


    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        console.log(  '52-  selected[i].id  =',  selected[i]  );
      factorial (objectArray, selected, selected[i].id  );
    }

    // return ( factorial (objectArray, selected, num ));
  }

};



factorial(objectArray, selected, 0);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? What issue are you having with the code that you have tried? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion, this answers the provided example:

```
let objectArray = [
      { id: 0, parentId: null},
      { id: 4, parentId: 3},
      { id: 1, parentId: 0},
      { id: 3, parentId: 2},
      { id: 2, parentId: 0}
];

let count = 0;

function findChildId(topId) {
    if(topId === 0) {
    count = objectArray.length - 1;
    return
  } 

  for(i = 1; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    if(objectArray[i].parentId === topId) {
        let childId = objectArray[i].id
      if(childId) {
        count++;
        findChildId(childId);
      }
    }
  }
}

findChildId(4); // use which ever id you are interest in
console.log(count);  // 0 for node 4
```

Comment: for  0 it should give 4 but it only gives 1

Comment: Sorry, about that. I've submitted an edit from my phone. Hopefully that fixes it up. If not I'll check again later when I'm at a pc

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach, create map from given object and add parent and children. From the resultant object find childCount as below :

```
var rels = [
{ id: 0, parentId: null}, 
{ id: 4, parentId: 3},
{ id: 1, parentId: 0}, 
{ id: 3, parentId: 2},
{ id: 2, parentId: 0}
];

 // create a map of nodes
 var nodeMap = distinct(rels);
 nodeMap = graph(rels,  nodeMap); // update parent and children

 childCount(3, nodeMap);
 childCount(0, nodeMap);

function distinct(nodes){
     return nodes.reduce(function(prev, curr){
          prev[curr.id] = {id:curr.id, parent:null, children:[]}
      return prev;
    }, {});
}

function graph(nodes, nodeMap){
    nodes.forEach(function(node){       
       if (node.parentId !== null) {        
           var parentNode = nodeMap[node.parentId]
           var childNode = nodeMap[node.id];

           console.log(parentNode, childNode)

           childNode.parent =  parentNode;
           parentNode.children.push(childNode);
       }
      });

   return nodeMap;
 }

 function childCount(id, nodeMap){
    var node = nodeMap[id];

    console.log('cc', id, node);

    return  node.children.reduce(function(prev, curr){ 
                         return prev + childCount(curr.id, nodeMap) 
                 }, 
                 node.children.length);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient to write is a simple recursive function like

```
 function countChild( objectArray, id) {
     let count = 0;
     objectArray.forEach( obj => {
         if( obj.parentId === id) {
            count = count + 1 + childCount(objectArray, obj.id);
         }
     });
     return count;
 }
```

However, it goes through the object array once for each and every descendant object located.

A method that collects member objects for each generation and only goes through the input array once per generation might be more efficient at least mathematically:

```js
let objectArray = [
{ id: 0, parentId: null}, 
{ id: 4, parentId: 3},
{ id: 1, parentId: 0}, 
{ id: 3, parentId: 2},
{ id: 2, parentId: 0}
];

function childCount(objectArray, id, children) {
     let count = 0;

     // count children of id value:

     if( !children) {
         children = new Set();
         objectArray.forEach( obj => {
             if( obj.parentId === id) {
                ++count;
                children.add(obj.id);
             }
         });
         if( count) {
             count += childCount( objectArray, null, children);
         }
         return count;
     }

     // or count children of children

     let nextGen = new Set();
     objectArray.forEach( obj => {
         if( children.has( obj.parentId)) {
             ++count;
             nextGen.add( obj.id);
         }
     });
     if( count) {
         count += childCount( objectArray, null, nextGen)
     }
     return count;
}

console.log(  childCount(objectArray, 0)  );
```

Whether the benefit of reducing the number of iterations through the input array is worth the additional complexity and overheads in a particular application is hard to say - I have not looked into it further.